# to judge whether hostname in /proc/cmdline is given a value

Tags: grep, hostname

```
root=/dev/sdb1 rootfstype=ext2 rootdelay=10 rw console=ttyS0,115200 ... hostname=
```

the above contents are in /proc/cmdline. I want to judge whether there is a value after "hostname=".

```
e.g. root=/dev/sdb1 rootfstype=ext2 rootdelay=10 rw console=ttyS0,115200 ... hostname=tank
```

my script is as follows.

```
#! /bin/bash
cat /proc/cmdline | grep  hostname=?*  #to judge if there is a value after hostname
if [ $? -eq 1 ]    #there is no value after hostname
    then
            echo "no hostname!"
            echo `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep model | cut -d "," -f 2 | \
                  tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]"` > /etc/hostname
    else
            echo "succeed!"
fi
```

However, "cat /proc/cmdline | grep  hostname=?*"  doesn't work as my expection.

the expected result is that I can judge whether there is a value after hostname by the scripts. if there is, I do nothing with /etc/hostname, otherwise, I will give a value to /etc/hostname.

PS: I can give hostname a value at the stage of bootup:

```
setenv sdboot 'setenv bootargs root=/dev/sdb1 rootfstype=ext2 rootdelay=10 rw console=$consoledev,$baudrate $othbootargs hostname=$hostname;'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have:

```
egrep -q '\bhostname=\S+' /proc/cmdline
```

Or

```
grep -Eq '\bhostname=\S+' /proc/cmdline
grep -Pq '\bhostname=\S+' /proc/cmdline
```

- `egrep` or `grep -E` makes use of extended regular expressions.
- `grep -P` makes use of Perl regex which also follows the format.
- From the manual: *The symbol `\b` matches the empty string at the edge of a word.*
- `\S+` makes it sure that there's a value assigned to it and is not a space.
- `-q` option tells `grep` to not produce any output and is helpful when you only want the exit code.

Your `if` block can also be just:

```
if egrep -q '\bhostname=\S+' /proc/cmdline; then
    echo 'succeed!'
else
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works! I have spent about one week on this job.

Comment: hi man. I need to ask you the other question. hope you could help me. If I want to get the value after hostname=, how could I do? e.g. hostname=tank, I want to get the value "tank".

Comment: Simply use special parameter expansion: `value=$(egrep -q '\bhostname=\S+' /proc/cmdline); value=${value#%*=}; echo "$value"`

Comment: Or use `sed`: `egrep -q '\bhostname=\S+' /proc/cmdline | sed 's|^hostname=||'`

Comment: Hey sorry man. I forgot, you shouldn't use `-q`. Can you try my commands again? Just exclude the `-q` option to `egrep`.

Comment: I'm sorry, your script doesn't work. this one works,cat /proc/cmdline | sed -e 's,.*hostname=\(\S*\).*,\1,'\ > etc/hostname  PS: how to make my command to be grey like yours

Comment: Well your sed command looks fine. You sure you don't need `-r` or `-E` for that?

Comment: you means which command, sed or egrep? I just want to get the value after `hostname`. At the same time, I cannot judge the position of `hostname`.

Comment: If it's sed I'd do `sed -E 's|.*\bhostname=([^ ]*).*|\1|' /proc/cmdline`. Or `sed -E 's|.*\bhostname=(\S*).*|\1|' /proc/cmdline`. Use `-r` if you don't have `-E`.

Comment: It is sad to tell you that the `sed` command cannot be used in my scripts because the script is under /etc/init.d/rcS, which is executed before the stage of runlevel 5, meaning that at this time the program `sed` has not be added into RAM. what could be used in such situation are the kernel built-in commands...So I need to change my idea...

Comment: @tank Do you have `busybox` loaded at that time already? Perhaps use busybox sed? `busybox sed`.

Comment: you are right!! `busybox sed` can be used!! Thank you very much!! you're almost my `lucky rain`!